# Force search results order by category

Tags: solspace

I have a channel with a category group. I need the search to order results if a certain category has been selected by placing them at the top, and entries with the same category to be then ordered by date.

Is this possible using solspace search?

Comment: Have you reviewed the documentation, primarily this area?http://www.solspace.com/docs/super_search/results/#category

Comment: I tried that but it doesnt appear to add relevance to the category. It is more of a filter. I think i need to move it from a category to a custom field and use http://www.solspace.com/docs/super_search/relevance_ordering/

Answer (score 2):

This isn't possible with Super Search as is. However, you could attempt to run a workaround with the [Preparse add-on](http://www.solspace.com/docs/preparse) (free). What it allows you to do is parse other content into a new custom field (let's call it "my_category_field") from an EE template (used only for formatting/parsing the entry data) at time of publishing/updating of entry. So, you could have Preparse set to load the "my_category_field" field with the usual category tags in your Preparse template:

```
{exp:channel:entries entry_id="{preparse_entry_id}"}
{categories}{category_name}{/categories}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

And Preparse will parse out the category data into a your "my_category_field" field, allowing you to then have Super Search results order the results by your "my_category_field" custom field + date.

Please let me know if that makes sense! :)

Comment: I did consider that using the Stash plugin instead. But i favour simplicity and so decided to move it from a category to a dropdown and managed to get it working.